# awk exact variable match, print remaining lines

Tags: awk, nawk

I have two files, If FILE2's column2 data(/usr, /opt/var) available in FILE1's column2, then print the remaining lines of FILE1.

The line order will vary, and the columns content also vary from server to server.

FILE1

```
JUDI /usr 94  
JUDI /var 78  
JUDI /usr/openv 80  
JUDI /opt 85  
JUDI /opt/var 75
```

FILE2

```
JUDI /usr 93  
JUDI /opt/var 70
```

OUTPUT as

```
JUDI /var 78  
JUDI /usr/openv 80  
JUDI /opt 85
```

I tried this code:

```
A=`awk '{print $2}' FILE2`
for i in $A
do
x=$i
nawk '$2 !~ /^"'\$\x'"/  {print $0}' FILE1
done
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post. [awk exact variable match, print remaining lines](http://askubuntu.com/q/697954) and [awk exact variable match, print remaining lines](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/243017).

Comment: Notwithstanding the cross-post, I don't consider this a low-quality question deserving of a downvote. It has usable sample data, an attempt to write some code, and expected output. Of course, the question in the Ubuntu forum might be a bit misplaced, since nothing about this is Ubuntu-specific.

Comment: @terdon , sorry for the cross post, Please remove the downvote .. am a new bee to this forums

Comment: I haven't downvoted. Please delete your cross-posts though. Other people are wasting their time on this and you already have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++} !($2 in a)' file2 file1
JUDI /var 78
JUDI /usr/openv 80
JUDI /opt 85
```

Tested in FreeBSD, but should work with just about every awk implementation.

The idea here is that you step through the first file, populating an array with the second field as a key, then step through the second file, printing only the lines whose second field are not a key in the array.

Comment: Thanks @ghoti , that works